# Did Paul establish the churches in Galatia?

Tags: galatians

(KJV)Galatians 1:6

> I marvel that ye are so soon removed from him that called you into the grace of Christ unto another gospel:

(KJV)Galatians 4:15

> Where is then the blessedness ye spake of? for I bear you record, that, if it had been possible, ye would have plucked out your own eyes, and have given them to me.

Could Paul have established the churches in Galatia for he makes reference to the Galatians as having heard the gospel before also he makes reference to himself in above texts as having been in galatia before

Comment: collen ndhlovu ... please meet [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Galatians). Hope you enjoy getting to know each other.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [time line at BibleHub.com](http://biblehub.com/timeline/new.htm) Paul visited Antioch of Pisidia, Iconium, Lystra and Derbe during his first missionary journey (Acts 13,14), circa 48 CE.

[image]
<sup>Paul's First Missionary Journey - [The Bible Journey.org](http://www.thebiblejourney.org/biblejourney1/9-pauls-journey-to-cyprus-pamphylia-galatia-/paul-starts-his-1st-missionary-journey/)</sup>

Since he wrote his letter to the church in Galatia around 54 CE, it is to be expected that it would contain references to events and conversations that took place during his earlier visit.

At the end of Paul's first missionary journey, the writer of Acts relates:

> <sup>26</sup> And thence sailed to Antioch, from whence they had been recommended to the grace of God for the work which they fulfilled. <sup>27</sup> And when they were come, and had gathered the church together, they rehearsed all that God had done with them, and how he had opened the door of faith unto the Gentiles. <sup>28</sup> And there they abode long time with the disciples.
>   -- Acts 14:26-28 (KJV)

There is little doubt that Paul established the churches in Galatia.